# Fetch the latest records from many-to-many relationship table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using `SQL Server 2008 R2`.

I am having `three tables` in my database are having `many-to-many` relationship as below.

```
TblServiceLevel     
Id  ServiceLevel    Code
1   C               1
2   R               1
3   V               1
4   R Test          4
5   C Test          4
6   S               2
7   K               3


TblUser 
Id  Name
1   A
2   B
3   C
4   D
5   E
6   F


TblUserServiceLevel         
Id  UserId  ServiceLevelId  Status
1   1       1               Active
2   1       1               Deactive
3   2       3               Active
4   3       4               Active
5   1       5               Active
6   5       1               Active
7   2       3               Deactive
8   3       4               Deactive
9   5       1               Deactive
10  2       3               Active
11  3       4               Active
12  4       1               Active
```

Now,

From this tables, I want distinct users that are exists in `TblUserServiceLevel` and 
having `latest service level ="Active"` and `ServiceLevel.Code <> 4.`

Can anyone help me?

The result is `2` and `4` user id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select t1.UserId
from TblUserServiceLevel t1
inner join (
    select UserId, max (Id) as maxId
    from TblUserServiceLevel
    group by UserId
) t2 on t1.UserId = t2.UserId and t1.Id = t2.maxId
inner join TblServiceLevel sl on t1.ServiceLevelId = sl.Id and sl.Code <> 4
where t1.Status = 'Active'
```

Comment: Thanks GriGrim !! Great solution.. SQL Experts are there in Stackoverflow now.. Yippi.. :)